# Jquery form validation no output

Tags: jquery, forms

Really strugglin to see the error on my form validation,

http://fiddle.jshell.net/U3G5P/

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra semicolon. If you use the "jshint" button, you'll see the error.

```
$(function () {

    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("#register").validate({
        errorElement: "div",
        rules: {
            // Specify the validation rules
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                minlength: 4
            },

            // Specify the validation error messages
            messages: {
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        } //REMOVED SEMICOLON HERE
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you deserve a case of beer! Been pulling my hair out!

Comment: No problem, it's always the little things that trip everything up! If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted. Thanks!